# Custom Ansible module throws unsupported arguments when passing list as parameter

Tags: python, ansible

I am writing custom module but when I put the type as list and pass the values like below, I get the error

> unsupported parameters

For type string it is working fine.

What is the correct way to pass the list arguments if, in the custom module, we have declared the type as list?

Usage:

```yaml
- test_module:
    url : 'htpp://xxxxx'
    computers:
      - a
      - b
```

*Modulexxxx.py*

```py
module_args = dict(
  url==dict(type='str', required=True),
  computers=dict(type='list', required=False)
)
```

Comment: Is the typo here a copy paste mistake or part of your issue: `url==dict(type='str', required=True),`? The `==` is bogus, it should be `url=dict(type='str', required=True),` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, the error

> Unsupported parameters for (test_module) module: computers

Means that you did not properly feed your expected parameters in the `argument_spec` of the instantiation of the object `AnsibleModule`.

Here is a MVP to have your arguments taken into account:

*test_module.py*

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule

def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec = dict(
            url = dict(type = 'str', required = True),
            computers = dict(type = 'list', required = False),
        )
    )

    params = module.params

    module.exit_json(
        received = {'url': params['url'], 'computers': params['computers']},
        changed = True
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Run with this couple of tasks

```yaml
- test_module:
    url : 'htpp://xxxxx'
    computers:
      - a
      - b
  register: test

- debug:
    var: test.received
```

This would yield:

```
TASK [test_module] ***********************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  test.received:
    computers:
    - a
    - b
    url: htpp://xxxxx
```